# Module injections vs Single application

Tags: angularjs

I have been working with AngularJs for a while and I now feel comfortable enough with it that I started to review my earlier work.

So I started out with following the basic tutorials and got used to setting up the application, controllers and services as following:

**Module injections**

```
// application.js
angular.module('appname',
    [ // dependencies
      'ui.router'
    , 'someController'    
    ]);

// somecontroller.js
angular.module('someController', [])        
    .controller('someCtrl',
        ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            // Some stuff
        }]);
```

And of course including js files in my index.html e.g.:

```
<script src="path/angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/application.js"></script>
<script src="path/somecontroller.js"></script>
```

Since I tend to separate all logic by feature (separate directory, own MV* structure per directory), I found that the list of dependencies can grow rather large. And also I think adding each controller, service etc. to the app dependencies is kind of a drag.

So I started to do it this way instead:

**Single application**

```
// application.js
var app = angular.module('appname',
    [ // dependencies
      'ui.router'
    ]);

// somecontroller.js
app.controller('someCtrl',
    ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // Some stuff
    }]);
```

The obvious win for doing it like this is that I do not longer have to add the controller reference to the app dependencies.

**So now my question(s) are:**

1. Besides the obvious, what is the difference between the 2 methods?
2. From the Angular perspective which of the methods is considered
   "good/bad practice"? And why?

Comment: You are not a pioneer with this question :) You’ll probably find the answers in this article: http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/

Comment: Wasn't trying to be pioneering the question or imply I found something new ;-) Just want to know the implications of each different approach. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second method is good. You add all controllers to your app main's module. If you want to truly group your code by feature, I recommend a third approach :

```
// application.js
angular.module('appname',
    [ 'ui.router'
    , 'appname.booking'    
    ]);

//booking.mod.js
angular.module('appname.booking', []);

//booking.ctrl.js
angular.module('appname.booking')        
    .controller('BookingCtrl', function ($scope) {
            // Some booking logic
        }]);
```

This way, you create a module per feature and obtain a project architecture easy to understand and navigate.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Somehow I didn't even consider this. It's a beautiful and organised solution and enables me to inject seperate feature logic as a module while keeping my application.js readable and relatively clean.

Answer (score 1):

In your first method you are creating different modules for your controller. That's why you have to inject your controller name at the time of creating Angular JS app.

```
angular.module('appName', ['controllerName']);
angular.module('controllerName', []);
```

In the second approach you are only creating a single app and you are attaching the controller to this app. In this case you don't have to inject the controller name at the time of creating the Angular JS app.

```
var app = angular.module('appName', []);
app.controller('controllerName', function(){});
```

About your second question, it depends on the type of application you are developing. For a small single page application a single app module will do fine

When working on large applications everything might not be contained on a single page, and by having features contained within modules it's much simpler to reuse modules across apps. So in this case your first approach is better.

You can create different modules like shown below and can inject to your app;

```
var sharedServicesModule = angular.module('sharedServices',[]);
sharedServices.service('NetworkService', function($http){});

var loginModule = angular.module('login',['sharedServices']);
loginModule.service('loginService', function(NetworkService){});
loginModule.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, loginService){});

var app = angular.module('app', ['sharedServices', 'login']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to read a bit more about [modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

The difference between your two approaches is that in the first one you create a different module for your controller and by injecting that module into the app dependencies you tell angular "by the way, I want the features that come with that module, too".

In your second approach, you only have a single huge module for the entire application, which means all the controllers, service, directives, .. will be automatically considered as part of the application.

Both approaches work, however having different modules for different functionality could help you structure you application better, as well as provide more reusability & easier testing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did re-read the suggested module section. And together with the answers here it somehow all came together. :-) I gave an upvote for your answer, because it did help me get there.